# Numeric Keypad - switch comma "," to period "." (German keyboard layout)

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support, numpad

The German decimal mark standard is a comma (e.g. 1.400,50 one-thousand-fourhundred-euro-and-fifty-cent).

Most apps use the US standard period. Is there a way to quickly switch the comma to a period on the numeric keypad (and back)?

[image]

Answer (score 31):

In Ubuntu 18.04 I couldn't find any appropriate option in "standard" settings (neither in **Devices** -> **Keyboard**, nor in **Region & Language**).

The "clickable" solution I found uses `gnome-tweak-tool` that I had previously installed for other reasons:
`sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool`

To run the tool hit Win button and type **Tweaks**.

In the app in **Keyboard & Mouse** tab click **Additional Layout Options** and open the **Numeric keypad Delete behavior** section.
Multiple of the available options there worked for me (I have selected **Four-level key with dot** as my default).

The nice thing with this solution is that the change is applied instantly as you select the option (no need to click apply or anything). This might be useful if you need to change temporarily to do something and go back to default - just leave the app open do your thing and click back when you are done.

Comment: I'm wondering what "Four-level key" refers to, but it may be because AltGr+NumDel gives you the dot again, while Shift+AltGr+NumDel gives you a narrow no-break space (`u+202f`). Rad!

Comment: That's exactly the point: this settings makes the Numeric Keypad Delete a "Four-level key", so you can use level modifiers keys (Shift and Alt-Gr) to switch between 4 possible options, as described in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey#Third_and_fourth_level_choosers . This means you can set it to use Alt-Gr to insert a period or a comma.

Comment: For confused potatoes like me, the "Delete" key is the same key where "." is.

Comment: @Klesun It's the key where the **.** or **,** is on the _numeric keypad_, the one marked with the orange square by OP in the image. On my physical keyboard it is marked with **.** and **Del**. In the OP's German layout image it is marked with **,** and **Del**.

Comment: This didn't work for me, running 22.04

Comment: This is great, was driving me nuts. I even had this problem when setting an English keyboard (qwerty), but locale Germany.

Answer (score 8):

There is an implemented option for `kpdl(dot)`:

```
setxkbmap de -option kpdl:dot
```

for permanent changes add the option to */etc/default/keyboard*

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="de"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS="kpdl:dot"

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

This way it will be independent from your xkb-data and safe on dist upgrade.

Comment: worked for me. thx

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a custom keyboard layout.

In `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/de`, add this:

```
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "dot" {
    include "de(basic)"
    include "kpdl(dot)"
    name[Group1]="German (dot as decimal separator)";
};
```

In `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml`, add this:

```
        <variant>
          <configItem>
            <name>dot</name>
            <description>German (dot as decimal separator)</description>
          </configItem>
        </variant>
```

After next reboot you'll be able to add the *German (dot as decimal separator)* layout and then switch easily between that layout and *German*.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 20.04 this can be achieved with gnome-tweaks.

To install gnome-tweaks, type in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

or without a terminal:

- Press the 'Win' button, or click on 'Activities'
- Type 'Ubuntu Software' and hit 'enter' or click on 'Ubuntu Software'
- Type 'gnome-tweaks'
- Select the 'Tweaks' software package
- Click on 'Install'

To run the tool, type in a terminal:

```
gnome-tweaks
```

or without a terminal

- Press the 'Win' button, or click on 'Activities',
- type 'Tweaks' and hit enter
- Click on 'Keyboard & Mouse'
- Click on 'Additional Layout Options'
- Click on 'Numeric keypad Delete behavior'
- Click on 'Four-level key with dot'

Now the ',' key behaves as it was a '.' key. If you need the ',' you can hold the 'alt gr' key and press ','.

You can also choose 'Legacy key with dot', and later change it back to 'Disabled' or 'Legacy key with comma'.

For people with a US international keyboard with a '.' on the numeric pad, but regularly need a ','. Select 'Four-level key with dot' if you more often need a '.', or 'Four-level key with comma' if you more often need the ','.

Answer (score 0):

As I couldn't google a way to do it for the Mate desktop: for Mate 1.24.1 start Keyboard Preferences, select Layouts and the button "Options".  Below "Layout of numeric keypad" there is an entry called "Legacy" which changes the comma to a dot.
That's the only thing it seems to change.

Answer (score -1):

Here are some ways to change it.
In may case it works with Keyboard settings > Layout > Options.
There is option for numeric Del button. Found myself easy.

Other way with xmodmap. I don't like it.

Both ways are here from awesome guys:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1377642

Comment: Please don't post links as answer. Reproduce the procedure here in your answer. If the URL dies your answer would be useless.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it's there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).